# Depurando as tags de debug

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

Topei com estas cinco tags [depuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depura%c3%a7%c3%a3o), [depurar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depurar), [depurador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depurador), [debug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug) e [debugger](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugger).

**Depuração** e **Depurar** tem um parágrafo introdutório parecido e depois tem ótimas explicações.

**Depurador** e **Debugger** são espelho uma da outra; cópia não, espelho. Boa explicação.

**Debug** é sinônimo de **Depuração**.

Minha sugestão:

- sinonimizar tudo;
- decidir por um fragmento unificador;
- decidir por um parágrafo introdutório;
- agregar as 3 explicações das 4 tags em uma tag maestra.
  <sup><sub>(o histórico mostra que dois usuários escreveram essas quatro wikis de tag)</sub></sup>

---

<sup>*Para facilitar a visualização/edição, seguem os textos atuais:*</sup>

## FRAGMENTOS E WIKIS DE TAG ATUAIS

### FRAGMENTOS

#### [depuração]

> Depuração é um processo metódico de encontrar e reduzir o número de erros ou defeitos em um software, dotando-o do comportamento esperado. Use esta tag para ferramentas de depuração ou para o processo em si, e não para qualquer problema que esteja impedindo o programa de funcionar.

#### [depurar]

> É o processo de encontrar e reduzir defeitos num aplicativo de software ou mesmo em hardware. Erros de software incluem aqueles que previnem o programa de ser executado e aqueles que produzem um resultado inesperado.

#### [depurador]

> Um depurador (em inglês: debugger) é um programa de computador usado para testar outros programas e fazer sua depuração, que consiste em encontrar os defeitos do programa.

### WIKIS

#### [depuração]

> [Depuração](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=debug%2C%20depurar%2C%20debugging%2C%20depura%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2C%20depurador&geo=BR&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1) (ou *debugging*) é um processo metódico de encontrar e reduzir o número de erros, ou defeitos, em um dado sistema (programa de computador ou hardware eletrônico), dotando-o do comportamento esperado.
>
> A depuração tende a ser mais difícil quando vários subsistemas estão fortemente acoplados, pois mudanças em um deles podem causar o surgimento de erros em outro.
>
> Muitos livros foram escritos sobre a depuração, uma vez que ela envolve inúmeros aspectos, incluindo depuração interativa, fluxo de controle, teste de integração, arquivos de log, o monitoramento (de aplicativos, do sistema), despejos de memória, perfilamento, Controle Estatístico de Processos e táticas especiais do projeto para melhorar a detecção, além de simplificar as mudanças.

#### [depurar]

> **Depurar** ou **Depuração** (em inglês: debugging, debug) é o processo de encontrar e reduzir defeitos num aplicativo de software ou mesmo em hardware. Erros de software incluem aqueles que previnem o programa de ser executado e aqueles que produzem um resultado inesperado.
>
> A depuração começa com a tentativa de reprodução do problema, o que pode não ser uma tarefa simples, como em computação paralela. Após a reprodução, o problema deve ser reduzido até sua essência, para facilitar a depuração. É um processo iterativo em que para cada redução, uma nova execução é feita para assegurar a reprodução do problema. Como analogia, pode-se considerar esse processo de redução como uma forma de divisão e conquista. Para automatizar a redução da entrada, métodos de depuração delta podem ser usados.

#### [depurador]

> Um **depurador** (em inglês: [debugger](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugger)) é um programa de computador usado para testar outros programas e fazer sua depuração, que consiste em encontrar os defeitos do programa.
>
> O código a ser examinado pode estar sendo executado sob uma máquina virtual, uma técnica que permite total flexibilidade de acesso aos estados da máquina virtual, que também é software. Mas os processadores modernos têm muitos recursos, que também facilitam o acesso a instruções do programa. Por exemplo, desde há muito tempo é possível interromper a execução de instruções do programa depurado em qualquer ponto e examinar o conteúdo de suas variáveis.
>
> Quando o programa aborta, o depurador mostra a posição no código fonte original, se for um depurador de código fonte, ou um depurador simbólico. Caso seja um depurador de linguagem de máquina, ele mostra a linha onde ocorreu o problema através de desmontagem.

---

**Material de apoio**: fiz a [seguinte pesquisa no Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=debug%2C%20depurar%2C%20debugging%2C%20depura%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2C%20depurador&geo=BR&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-1):

[image: google trends no brasil sobre as tags envolvidas]

Agora em outubro, os valores são os seguintes:

[image]

<sup>PS: considerar que "depuração" pode ser de figado, e "depurador" pode ser de ar.</sup>

Comment: Concordo. Só ainda não estou totalmente confiante de que `depuração` e `depurador` (e seus respectivos derivados) devem ser uma tag só...

Comment: /esperando manifestação dos craques da casa/ :)

Comment: @Gabe Eu voto por termos uma única tag. Mesmo que a pergunta seja sobre uma ferramenta, ou mais de uma, ou ferramentas em geral, `debug` (ou depuração) ainda funcionaria bem. Vale mais colocar tags adicionais com o nome da ferramenta específica se necessário

Comment: +1. Mas vou avisando que da última vez que sugeri transformar uma tag em inglês em uma em português fui bastante negativado aqui.

Comment: @Pablo , eu já não concordo nisso, acredito que devíamos manter as origens, até porque `IF` não é `SE` e `while` nunca vai ser `enquanto`, na maioria esmagadora das linguagens, acho que se manter fiel a termos lá de fora ajuda a se conectar melhor com a programação de modo geral, inglês, the universal lenguage, e ponto! Talvez essa seja uma discussão para outro tópico, né.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Você pegou maus exemplos. Claro que, tratando-se de palavras-chave da linguagem, não tem como traduzir. Mas estamos falando de conceitos que possuem traduções claras e simples aqui. E, com essa ideia de inglês "universal language", não teríamos o pt.stackoverflow.com . Recomendo a você ler a publicação original no Stack Overflow chamada "Can't we all be reasonable and speak English?", na qual anunciaram o lançamento do SO em português, para entender o que eu quero dizer.

Comment: @Pablo , certamente fiz uma comparação entre coisas diferentes, gosto da resposta do Sergio(mais parecida com minha opinião), veja só: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/764/traduzir-tags-para-r%C3%B3tulos , acho que resolver problemas do mundo da programação(proposto pela stack) é diferente de querer mudar o que já esta enraizado na "cultura da programação", nós falamos debug, na china eles falam debug, é a "comunicação universal da programação", esse é o ponto chave e acho importante manter isso.  É por ai minha opinião, só acho desnecessário se apegar a isso, que está em todo lugar.

Comment: @Pablo: Se o programador vive numa bolha aportuguesada, então, sim, debug é uma palavra estranha. Pra todo o resto que tem que batalhar seu caminho em meio a toneladas de textos em inglês, debug é feijão com arroz. . . . *"fui bastante negativado"*, jejeje, [isto é ser bastante negativado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2022/who-watches-the-watchmen).

Comment: @brasofilo Eu nunca disse que debug é uma palavra estranha. Eu acho que esse assunto merece uma publicação em blog ou algo assim, porque tá tendo muito mal entendido... O que eu quero dizer é: dadas duas palavras igualmente claras e compreensíveis para quem fala português (que eu acredito ser o caso de debug e de random), então é preferível, no SOpt, dada a *visão inicial* do projeto, como visto na publicação à qual fiz referência, a versão em português.

Comment: @Gabe, pelo que li, existem softwares específicos para fazer debug, os debuggers. Acho que, normalmente, são muito poucas as perguntas sobre determinado debugger e talvez fosse o caso, como diz o bfavaretto, de usar "[tag:debugger-Nome-da-Ferramenta]".

Comment: @brasofilo Nada contra a sugestão do bfavaretto. Eu fui o primeiro a votar nela. Mas pelo que entendi, ele sugeriu usar a tag `debug` e, caso a pergunta seja sobre um *debugger*, outra tag na pergunta `nome-do-debugger`. Então uma pergunta, por exemplo, sobre [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) receberia as tags [`debug`, `pdb`]. O que é uma solução muito boa.

Comment: @Gabe: capisce, me parece perfecto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bateu uma falta do que fazer e arranjei a coisa toda assim:

1. [debug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug) agora é a tag principal e [depuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depura%c3%a7%c3%a3o) é sinônimo, conforme os dados do Google Trends.
2. [depurar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depurar), [depurador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depurador) e [debugger](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugger) agora são sinônimos de [debug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug).

Minha sugestão é colocar nas perguntas uma tag com o nome do *debugger* específico quando isso for relevante. Geralmente faz sentido colocar também a tag da linguagem de programação a ser debugada.

> <strike>**Falta agora compilar o conteúdo daqueles wikis todos em um mais completo para a tag [debug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debug). Alguém se habilita?**</strike> [o @brasofilo já resolveu :)]

Comment: Fiz um remix do textos anteriores; acho que tá legal até o próximo tag-editor entrar em ação.